# Updating the database after editing the ASP.NET User using context in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am struggling to persist the new data to the database because I can't find the proper `ApplicationDbContext` method. First of all, let me show you the steps that led to this. The following method shows how got the necessary fields from the Db in order to fill in the fields in the Edit view.

```
 public ActionResult UsersWithRoles()
    {
        var usersWithRoles = (from user in context.Users
                              select new
                              {
                                  UserId = user.Id,
                                  Username = user.UserName,
                                  Email = user.Email,
                                  RoleNames = (from userRole in user.Roles
                                               join role in context.Roles on userRole.RoleId
                                               equals role.Id
                                               select role.Name).ToList()
                              }).ToList().Select(p => new UserViewModels()

                              {
                                  UserId = p.UserId,
                                  Username = p.Username,
                                  Email = p.Email,
                                  Role = string.Join(",", p.RoleNames)
                              });


        return View(usersWithRoles);
    }
```

This works fine, the view looks like this:

[image: Edit]

Right. Now, if I click "Save", this is the method that is supposed to pass the new data to the database:

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(UserViewModels user)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            context.Update(user);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return null;
        }
        return null;

    }
```

In the tutorial that I've followed, `context.Update` was used - however, in my case, it says that `ApplicationDbContext` does not have a method called `Update`. Also, return RedirectToAction does not work because

> it can not convert System.Web.Mvc.RedirectToRouteResult to
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult

How should the latter method be written in order to work properly?

**csproj** info:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.Default.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.Default.props')" />
  <Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.2.0.1\build\net46\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.2.0.1\build\net46\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props')" />
  <Import Project="..\packages\EntityFramework.6.3.0\build\EntityFramework.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\EntityFramework.6.3.0\build\EntityFramework.props')" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>
    </ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{96AED44B-7760-489B-BC37-21451980A753}</ProjectGuid>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>ARA_Tool</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>ARA Tool</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <MvcBuildViews>false</MvcBuildViews>
    <UseIISExpress>true</UseIISExpress>
    <Use64BitIISExpress />
    <IISExpressSSLPort>44365</IISExpressSSLPort>
    <IISExpressAnonymousAuthentication />
    <IISExpressWindowsAuthentication />
    <IISExpressUseClassicPipelineMode />
    <UseGlobalApplicationHostFile />
    <NuGetPackageImportStamp>
    </NuGetPackageImportStamp>
    <TypeScriptToolsVersion>3.5</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\EntityFramework.6.3.0\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="EntityFramework.SqlServer, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\EntityFramework.6.3.0\lib\net45\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.2.2.3\lib\net45\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.2.2.3\lib\net45\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.2.2.3\lib\net45\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions.2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions.2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Abstractions, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Abstractions.2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.2.0.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Owin, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Owin.4.1.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.4.1.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Owin.Security, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Owin.Security.4.1.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.Security.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.4.1.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.4.1.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google.4.1.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount.4.1.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.4.1.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter.4.1.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.12.0.3\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Buffers, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Buffers.4.5.0\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Buffers.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Reference Include="System.Memory, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Memory.4.5.1\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Memory.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Numerics" />
    <Reference Include="System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=4.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Numerics.Vectors.4.4.0\lib\net46\System.Numerics.Vectors.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.4.5.1\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Text.Encodings.Web, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Text.Encodings.Web.4.5.0\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Text.Encodings.Web.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Web.DynamicData" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Entity" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.ApplicationServices" />
    <Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Extensions" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Abstractions" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Routing" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="System.Configuration" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Services" />
    <Reference Include="System.EnterpriseServices" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>True</Private>
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.1.0.0.0\lib\net40\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http">
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http.WebRequest">
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Helpers, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>True</Private>
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.2.7\lib\net45\System.Web.Helpers.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>True</Private>
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.5.2.7\lib\net45\System.Web.Mvc.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Optimization">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.1.1.3\lib\net40\System.Web.Optimization.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>True</Private>
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.3.2.7\lib\net45\System.Web.Razor.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Web.WebPages, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>True</Private>
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.2.7\lib\net45\System.Web.WebPages.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Web.WebPages.Deployment, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>True</Private>
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.2.7\lib\net45\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <Private>True</Private>
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.3.2.7\lib\net45\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="WebGrease">
      <Private>True</Private>
      <HintPath>..\packages\WebGrease.1.6.0\lib\WebGrease.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Antlr3.Runtime">
      <Private>True</Private>
      <HintPath>..\packages\Antlr.3.5.0.2\lib\Antlr3.Runtime.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Owin">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Owin.1.0\lib\net40\Owin.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.4.0.0\lib\net451\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="App_Start\BundleConfig.cs" />
    <Compile Include="App_Start\FilterConfig.cs" />
    <Compile Include="App_Start\IdentityConfig.cs" />
    <Compile Include="App_Start\RouteConfig.cs" />
    <Compile Include="App_Start\Startup.Auth.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Controllers\AccountController.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Controllers\HomeController.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Controllers\ManageController.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Controllers\ManageUsersController.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Global.asax.cs">
      <DependentUpon>Global.asax</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Models\AccountViewModels.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Models\IdentityModels.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Models\ManageViewModels.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Models\UserViewModels.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Startup.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Content\bootstrap-theme.css" />
    <Content Include="Content\bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
    <Content Include="Content\bootstrap.css" />
    <Content Include="Content\bootstrap.min.css" />
    <Content Include="favicon.ico" />
    <Content Include="fonts\glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg" />
    <Content Include="Global.asax" />
    <Content Include="Content\Site.css" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\bootstrap.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\bootstrap.min.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\esm\popper-utils.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\esm\popper-utils.min.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\esm\popper.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\esm\popper.min.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\index.js.flow" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\esm\popper.min.js.map" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\esm\popper.js.map" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\esm\popper-utils.min.js.map" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\esm\popper-utils.js.map" />
    <Content Include="fonts\glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2" />
    <Content Include="fonts\glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff" />
    <Content Include="fonts\glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf" />
    <Content Include="fonts\glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot" />
    <Content Include="Content\bootstrap.min.css.map" />
    <Content Include="Content\bootstrap.css.map" />
    <Content Include="Content\bootstrap-theme.min.css.map" />
    <Content Include="Content\bootstrap-theme.css.map" />
    <None Include="Scripts\jquery-3.4.1.intellisense.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\jquery-3.4.1.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\jquery-3.4.1.min.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\jquery-3.4.1.slim.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" />
    <None Include="Scripts\jquery.validate-vsdoc.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\jquery.validate.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\jquery.validate.min.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\modernizr-2.8.3.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\popper-utils.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\popper-utils.min.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\popper.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\popper.min.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\src\index.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\src\methods\defaults.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\src\methods\destroy.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\src\methods\disableEventListeners.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\src\methods\enableEventListeners.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\src\methods\placements.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\src\methods\update.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\src\modifiers\applyStyle.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\src\modifiers\arrow.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\src\modifiers\computeStyle.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\src\modifiers\flip.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\src\modifiers\hide.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\src\modifiers\index.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\src\modifiers\inner.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\src\modifiers\keepTogether.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\src\modifiers\offset.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\src\modifiers\preventOverflow.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\src\modifiers\shift.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\src\utils\clockwise.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\src\utils\computeAutoPlacement.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\src\utils\debounce.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\src\utils\find.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\src\utils\findCommonOffsetParent.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\src\utils\findIndex.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\src\utils\getBordersSize.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\src\utils\getBoundaries.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\src\utils\getBoundingClientRect.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\src\utils\getClientRect.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\src\utils\getFixedPositionOffsetParent.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\src\utils\getOffsetParent.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\src\utils\getOffsetRect.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\src\utils\getOffsetRectRelativeToArbitraryNode.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\src\utils\getOppositePlacement.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\src\utils\getOppositeVariation.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\src\utils\getOuterSizes.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\src\utils\getParentNode.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\src\utils\getPopperOffsets.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\src\utils\getReferenceNode.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\src\utils\getReferenceOffsets.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\src\utils\getRoot.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\src\utils\getRoundedOffsets.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\src\utils\getScroll.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\src\utils\getScrollParent.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\src\utils\getStyleComputedProperty.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\src\utils\getSupportedPropertyName.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\src\utils\getViewportOffsetRectRelativeToArtbitraryNode.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\src\utils\getWindow.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\src\utils\getWindowSizes.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\src\utils\includeScroll.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\src\utils\index.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\src\utils\isBrowser.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\src\utils\isFixed.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\src\utils\isFunction.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\src\utils\isIE.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\src\utils\isModifierEnabled.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\src\utils\isModifierRequired.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\src\utils\isNumeric.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\src\utils\isOffsetContainer.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\src\utils\removeEventListeners.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\src\utils\runModifiers.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\src\utils\setAttributes.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\src\utils\setStyles.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\src\utils\setupEventListeners.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\umd\popper-utils.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\umd\popper-utils.min.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\umd\popper.js" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\umd\popper.min.js" />
    <Content Include="Web.config" />
    <Content Include="Web.Debug.config">
      <DependentUpon>Web.config</DependentUpon>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="Web.Release.config">
      <DependentUpon>Web.config</DependentUpon>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="Views\Web.config" />
    <Content Include="Views\_ViewStart.cshtml" />
    <Content Include="Views\Shared\Error.cshtml" />
    <Content Include="Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml" />
    <Content Include="Views\Home\About.cshtml" />
    <Content Include="Views\Home\Contact.cshtml" />
    <Content Include="Views\Home\Index.cshtml" />
    <Content Include="Views\Account\_ExternalLoginsListPartial.cshtml" />
    <Content Include="Views\Account\ConfirmEmail.cshtml" />
    <Content Include="Views\Account\ExternalLoginConfirmation.cshtml" />
    <Content Include="Views\Account\ExternalLoginFailure.cshtml" />
    <Content Include="Views\Account\ForgotPassword.cshtml" />
    <Content Include="Views\Account\ForgotPasswordConfirmation.cshtml" />
    <Content Include="Views\Account\Login.cshtml" />
    <Content Include="Views\Account\Register.cshtml" />
    <Content Include="Views\Account\ResetPassword.cshtml" />
    <Content Include="Views\Account\ResetPasswordConfirmation.cshtml" />
    <Content Include="Views\Account\SendCode.cshtml" />
    <Content Include="Views\Account\VerifyCode.cshtml" />
    <Content Include="Views\Manage\AddPhoneNumber.cshtml" />
    <Content Include="Views\Manage\ChangePassword.cshtml" />
    <Content Include="Views\Manage\Index.cshtml" />
    <Content Include="Views\Manage\ManageLogins.cshtml" />
    <Content Include="Views\Manage\SetPassword.cshtml" />
    <Content Include="Views\Manage\VerifyPhoneNumber.cshtml" />
    <Content Include="Views\Shared\Lockout.cshtml" />
    <Content Include="Views\Shared\_LoginPartial.cshtml" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\umd\popper.min.js.map" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\umd\popper.js.map" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\umd\popper.js.flow" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\umd\popper-utils.min.js.map" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\umd\popper-utils.js.map" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\README.md" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\popper.min.js.map" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\popper.js.map" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\popper-utils.min.js.map" />
    <Content Include="Scripts\popper-utils.js.map" />
    <Content Include="Views\ManageUsers\UsersWithRoles.cshtml" />
    <Content Include="Views\ManageUsers\Edit.cshtml" />
    <Content Include="Views\ManageUsers\CreateUser.cshtml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="App_Data\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
```

Comment: What is the type of your context variable? IdentityDbContext or DbContext?

Comment: What is the version of asp.net are you using?

Comment: It is IdentityDbContext. As for the version, I suppose it's 2.2.6

Comment: I'm busy now to answer with a good example. But you can follow Travis answer. If have any problem I can provide an answer latter.

Comment: @LuttiCoelho I followed Travis' answer but couldn't find a way. Please check my reply on his post out and perhaps give me some tips to fix the issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem, like @TravisActon said is that your are expecting that EF auto convert the `UserViewModels` class to `IdentityUser`. You can do exactly as Travis explained at his answer. I just want to give you a second option. Using `UserManager` class that gives you a lot of functions to handle users and roles.

**Case you are using Asp.Net Framework with OWIN** Pretty sure you are.

First add this using on your controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
```

Then make a few change on your method:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(UserViewModels userViewModel)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View(userViewModel);

    // Get UserManager from OwinContext needs "using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;"
    var userManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

    var appUser = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(userViewModel.UserId);
    if (appUser == null)
        return await Task.Run<ActionResult>(() => RedirectToAction("UserNotFound", userViewModel));

    appUser.UserName = userViewModel.Username;
    appUser.Email = userViewModel.Email;

    // Updates the user information with UserManager
    await userManager.UpdateAsync(appUser);

    // Get all roles from user.
    var currentUserRoles = await userManager.GetRolesAsync(appUser.Id);

    // Remove all current roles fro this user. You can skip it if you don't need it.
    var removeCurrentRolesResult = await userManager.RemoveFromRolesAsync(appUser.Id, currentUserRoles.ToArray());

    // Verify if any error occours
    if(!removeCurrentRolesResult.Succeeded)
    {
        // Add errors to ModelState.
        removeCurrentRolesResult.Errors.ToList().ForEach(error => ModelState.AddModelError("Role", error));

        return View(userViewModel);
    }

    // get userRoles from text to an array of string;
    var newRoles = userViewModel.Role.Split(',').Select(_ => _.Trim());

    // Adds user to the new role
    var addRoleResult = await userManager.AddToRolesAsync(appUser.Id, newRoles.ToArray());

    if (!addRoleResult.Succeeded)
    {
          // handle errors like removeCurrentRolesResult
          return View(userViewModel);
    }

    return await Task.Run<ActionResult>(() => RedirectToAction("UsersWithRoles"));
}
```

**Case you are using Asp.Net Core 2+**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit([FromService] UserManager userManager, UserViewModels userViewModel)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View(userViewModel);

    var userModel = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(userViewModel.Id);
    if(userModel == null)
    {
        return await Task.Run<ActionResult>(() => RedirectToAction("UserNotFound", userViewModel));
    }

    // Updates the user information with UserManager
    userManager.SetUserNameAsync(userModel, userViewModel.UserName);
    userManager.SetEmailAsync(userModel, userViewModel.Email);

    // Get all roles from user.
    var currentUserRoles = await userManager.GetRolesAsync(userModel);

    // Remove all current roles fro this user. You can skip it if you don't need it.
    var removeCurrentRolesResult = await userManager.RemoveFromRolesAsync(appUser, currentUserRoles);

    // Verify if any error occours
    if(!removeCurrentRolesResult.Succeeded)
    {
        // Add errors to ModelState.
        removeCurrentRolesResult.Errors.ToList().ForEach(t => ModelState.AddModelError("Role", t.Description));

        return View(userViewModel);
    }

    // get userRoles from text to an array of string;
    var newRoles = userViewModel.Roles.Split(',').Select(_ => _.Trim());

    // Adds user to the new role
    var addRoleResult = await _userManager.AddToRolesAsync(userModel, newRoles);

    if (!addRoleResult.Succeeded)
    {
      // handle errors like removeCurrentRolesResult
      return View(userViewModel);
    }


    // Return redirect to action object without need to remove async from method.
    return await Task.Run<ActionResult>(() => RedirectToAction("UserNotFound", userModel));
}
```

The second problem, with redirects, is because `RedirectToAction` is an `IActionResult` and your method returns a `Task<IActionResult>` so to solve this you need to change return type of your method to `IActionResult` or call `RedirectToAction` into an `async` call. Like this:

```
return await Task.Run<ActionResult>(() => RedirectToAction("ActionName", model));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I have a few issues: The first one is that `[FromService]` attribute could not be found. Is it something that can be used only in AspNetCore? Secondly, line `return await Task.Run<IActionResult>(() => RedirectToAction("UserNotFound", userViewModel));` returns the error `cannot convert lambda expression to type because it is not a delegate type`. Moreover, it also couldn't find the method `SetUserNameAsync`, whereas `SetEmailAsync` worked. Lastly, variable `appUser` was not found. What exactly should it be? Thank you for any help regarding this issue!

Comment: [FromService] only works at Asp.net core. As you said you are using version 2.2.6 I imagine that's your asp.net core version.

Comment: appUser was my mistake. It should be userModel. I'll fix it on my answer

Comment: SetUserNameAsync is a method that exists in Asp.net identity core 2+ This is the version you are using?

Comment: My mistake - It's a ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework), not an ASPNetCore.

Comment: What version? 2.2.6 is very old. Can you share your .csproj file as xml?

Comment: I didn't know how to make it as .xml file, but here's the whole project: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/64b1d8bfef408f28536395deddf806cd20191210093444/9f148b

Comment: You can do it by right click on csproj file and open with notepad

Comment: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/70c90681c71528d8a2c217dbc539f63420191210124404/f9b2d6 There you go!

Comment: @Questieme I already updated my answer with a solution for Asp.Net Framework version. I'm pretty sure that will solve your problem.

Comment: And please let's keep all code needed to solve any problem inside stack overflow. We'll help more people this way.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I really appreciate your help on this matter. I will edit the OP so all the information given on outer sites will also be available here. I am sorry for any inconvenience this has created!

Comment: No inconvenience at all. Just make it usefull for other users that have the same problem.

Answer (score 4):

You are parsing your ORM generated user model into a self defined viewModel, asking the user to edit it then expecting your DB context to automagically convert it back over and save. Your DB context has no automatic concept of how to convert your viewmodel back to your model. It is just an abstract class mapping over your database. You have to explicitly do that yourself or explore options such as auto-mapper to map the two classes together.

A quick non-tested example on your high level object

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(UserViewModels user)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

      var u = context.Users.where(a => a.Id == UserId).FirstOrDefault();
      if(u != null)
      {
        u.UserName = user.UserName
        so on.....
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("CompleteActionName");
      }

        return RedirectToAction("UserNotFound", user);
    }
    return View(user);

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your example. I am sorry I couldn't come back with an answer earlier. I am having two issues - first would be how can I access the AspNetUserRoles table in order to change the role of a certain user? Secondly, I am still having issues with the RedirectToAction and View methods because they can not be converted from Web.Mvc.RedirectToRouteResult to AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult. Could you give me some tips to solve these two issues, please?

Comment: An update for the statement above: I removed the Async things and I fixed the RedirectToAction part. However, I am still having issues passing the updated Role.